# How to choose LVM mapping mode when installing Ubuntu server 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, server, raid, lvm

I would like to create a volume group with *striped* mode on top of 2 RAID-1 devices.

The issue here is I cannot choose `striped` when configuring LVM at installation stage. It's always be `linear`.